# Encoding issues during the extraction text from pdf file using pdfplumber

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, data-extraction, pdfplumber

I would like to extract the content of the following pdf file but it returns a meaningless result. I assume that it might be related to the **encoding** side of the file but the same extraction code works for many other files on the same infrastructure. This is not a single file which does not handled by the following script, there are some other cases as well. However, I have only placed here an example. I realized that if I copy/paste the text content of this file to my notepad, it is not properly pasted as well. The pasted text is not that bad I placed it at the bottom but it is not acceptable as well.
How should I approach to this problem? Any suggestions ?

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib3
import pdfplumber
import io

def extract_text_from_pdf_by_url(url):
    all_text = ''

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    temp = io.BytesIO()
    temp.write(http.request("GET", url).data)
    try:    # to verify is the url has valid pdf file!
        pdf = pdfplumber.open(temp)
        for pdf_page in pdf.pages:
            single_page_text = pdf_page.extract_text()
            # TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
            if single_page_text is not None: 
                all_text += '\n' + single_page_text
        pdf.close()
    except:
        pass
    return all_text


url  = '4yM2t3s0uI33S.pdf'
text = extract_text_from_pdf_by_url(url)
print(text)
```

It returns:

> Şİİİıı  ı İİİ İıŞİ
>
> ıöö ç ıı    ııçıı  öİ ı ıçıüüışü   üüğöüüıışı
>
> ıİÖıİ
>
> ö ıüö ıöğğ ı ç şüıııııı ş
>
> ...

Comment: The output I placed is retrieved based on the above code execution. The one you placed probably manually copied and pasted rather than pdfplumber, is that righ? What do you mean by OCR? I am not using any optical character recognition method here. For that reason, I am assuming that it might be related encoding or font family issues. Not sure!

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question, you may try [textract](https://pypi.org/project/textract/) or [pdf2txt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) to see if any works.

Comment: @KJ As I explained throughout the question, I need to find the reason instead of replacing the alternative document because this is not a single case.

Comment: If you want the reason why text extraction from some specific files fails while it usually works, you obviously need to share the file in question. Otherwise all you get is a (probably incomplete) list of possible reasons for text extraction failures.

Comment: Ah, after your question popped up again today, I looked at your question _before_ your edit, and there indeed is a working URL in the code. Inspection of that PDF shows that there is no reason for a text extractor to extract as little as you show pdfplumber extracts. The errors in the copy&paste result from Adobe Reader, on the other hand, are due to the bad OCR information embedded in the file. To improve them you have to run that file through OCR yourself using better (or at least better configured) OCR software.